# Unable to login with key after disabling password authentication

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Earlier I used to login with the original pem key file generated at instance launch time.

```
ssh -i /path/to/key.pem ubuntu@instance-dns-name.com
```

I tried to stop password authentication and made the following changes in sshd_config.

```
 ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
 PasswordAuthentication no
 UsePAM no
```

The key login stopped working and gives me 'Permission Denied(publicKey)' error.

Answer (score 0):

The created .pem file can only be used during installation for security reasons. Before actually disabling PasswordAuthernticatio (and essentially locking yourself out). You should have added a public key.

In your amazon console you should have a page called add keypair you should be able to fix it there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the user in questions doesn't have a password set. If you set the password to anything (anything except the empty string!) you will be able to log in (without password, with passwordless authentication).